# Xamarin No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@style/DesignTheme'). App1.Droid

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am new to Xamarin. So I started a shared project. Then I google some link to add material design and did the following.

1. I created the styles.xml.(I dont understand why the resources/value folder is not seen in visual studio but when I manually go the directory I could see so I created manually in there with the following content.

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ? >
   <resources>
       <style name="DesignTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
           <item name="windowNoTitle" >true </item >
           <item name="windowActionBar" >false </item >
           <item name="colorPrimary" >@color/primary </item >
           <item name="colorPrimaryDark" >@color/primary_dark </item >
           <item name="colorAccent" >@color/accent </item > 
       </style >
   </resources >
   ```
2. Next I change the manifest as below.I added this android:theme="@style/DesignTheme"

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
       <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />
       <application android:label="App1.Droid" android:theme="@style/DesignTheme"></application>
   </manifest>
   ```
3. I just tried to build and I got this error No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@style/DesignTheme'). but the manifest shows this now. Why is it different then in step 2?

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="App1.Droid">
       <!--suppress UsesMinSdkAttributes-->
       <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />
       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
       <application android:label="App1.Droid" android:theme="@style/DesignTheme" android:name="android.app.Application" android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:debuggable="true">
           <activity android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="App1" android:name="md50170a25da682dd459b9251c65ebe3a7a.MainActivity">
               <intent-filter>
                   <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                   <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
               </intent-filter>
           </activity>
           <provider android:name="mono.MonoRuntimeProvider" android:exported="false" android:initOrder="2147483647" android:authorities="App1.Droid.mono.MonoRuntimeProvider.__mono_init__" />
           <!--suppress ExportedReceiver-->
           <receiver android:name="mono.android.Seppuku">
               <intent-filter>
                   <action android:name="mono.android.intent.action.SEPPUKU" />
                   <category android:name="mono.android.intent.category.SEPPUKU.App1.Droid" />
               </intent-filter>
           </receiver>
       </application>
   </manifest>
   ```

The full error is .

No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@style/DesignTheme'). App1.Droid  C:\Users\ns\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\App1\App1\App1.Droid\obj\Debug\android\manifest\AndroidManifest.xml

```
Under the Nuget Package Manager I can see the installed list shows this Xamarin.Android.Support.Design is installed for version v24.2.1
```

Comment: I formatted accordingly when I press edit I could see my codes? Any help on the editing?

Comment: Can you add the full code from styles.xml? Also, if the folder isn't showing up in VS, above solution explorer you need to click "Show All Files" to show items that are not included in your project. If it shows up, right click and select "Include In Project."

Comment: I have added the full codes but it just seems not to appear. Yes in vs the folder did not show up in full. Now it was not shown up any where?

Comment: I got no choice but to show here the styles.xml <resources  >
            <style name="DesignTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" >
              <item name="windowNoTitle" >true </item >
                 <item name="windowActionBar" >false </item >
                    <item name="colorPrimary" >@color/primary </item >
                    <item name="colorPrimaryDark" >@color/primary_dark </item >
                    <item name="colorAccent" >@color/accent </item > </style >
            </resources >

Comment: I tried many times to edit it just does not come out with all my codes?

Comment: I edited your code to show your xml. It seems like your problem may be that your styles.xml may not be included in the project. Try adding it like I described a few comments ago.

Comment: I am a bit lost here? Do you mean to add via this . but why is it hidden in the first place is it a xamarin setting?

Comment: If you add files outside of Visual Studio they are not automatically included in the project. If you add them within Visual Studio they will be included, otherwise you need to manually include them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126415/discussion-between-user5313398-and-max-hampton).

Answer (score 0):

in `MainActivity`, in

```
[Activity(Label = "appName", ScreenOrientation = Android.Content.PM.ScreenOrientation.Portrait, MainLauncher = true)]
```

Remove them.